# check if array values contain another array's values and get the relevant key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array of country names like this:

```
$countryList = array(
"AF" => "Afghanistan",
"AL" => "Albania",
"DZ" => "Algeria",
# [...]
);
```

Another array, `$uniList`, contains strings with university affiliations, e.g.:

```
$uniList = array(
14 => array("id" => 14, "uni" => "University of Kabul, Afghanistan"),
20 => array("id" => 21, "uni" => "University Tirana, Albania, Department of Chemistry"),
23 => array("id" => 23, "uni" => "Oxford, U.K."),
# [...]
);
```

I want to loop through all `$uniList`-values and see whether any of the country names in `$countryList` appear there.

If a country is found, I would like to insert the country code (the array key from `$countryList`, e.g. `AF` for `Afghanistan`) into a MySQL row.

Something like this:

```
foreach($uniList as $row) {

   if($row['uni'] contains any of $countryList) { # perhaps strpos()?

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET column = :countrycode WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindValue(":countrycode", $countryList[key]);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $row['id']);
        $stmt->execute();

   }

}
```

How is it possible to achieve it?

My goal, in the end, is to have a MySQL table that should look similar to this:

```
| id | uni                                                 | country     |
| -- | --------------------------------------------------- | ----------- |
| 14 | University of Kabul, Afghanistan                    | Afghanistan |
| 20 | University Tirana, Albania, Department of Chemistry | Albania     |
| 23 | Oxford, U.K.                                        | U.K.        |
| 45 | University of Vienna                                | NULL        |
```

Comment: Why you have "INSERT... WHERE..."?

Comment: @ManuelGuzman, oh, I corrected it to `UPDATE ... SET ...`. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need a nested loop and [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Something like this

```
foreach($countryList as $abr => $country) {
    foreach($uniList as $uni) {
        if(strpos($uni['uni'], $country) !== false) {
            
            //insert
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET column = :countrycode WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->execute([
                'countrycode' => $country,
                'id' => $uni['id']
            ]);
            
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the text to match regardless of case, use [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: Perfect, it works, thank you! (And sorry -- it should have been `UPDATE ... SET ...`, of course, and not `INSERT ...`)